# xampp directly open my html file

Tags: xampp

I created folder called en407 and inside it i create a file called assigment that contain html , css and also php.

> http://localhost/en407b/

When i click on the assginmnt file , i should let me choose what file to open

> http://localhost/en407b/assignment

but the link directly go to my html file which is index.html and the link remains

> http://localhost/en407b/assignment

in my assignment file , it contain index.html , index2.html and other....

how to fix it???

Answer (score 0):

At first you can't run PHP in .html files because the server does not recognize it as valid till you tell it to do it. To do this create a .htaccess file in your root web directory and add this line inside it:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html
```

This will tell Apache to process files with a .htm or .html file extension as PHP files.